# Can someone explain the jQuery/JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT specific code of the Bootstrap 4 Button Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a general idea of why no conflict is important and what's going on here. However, I'm trying to better understand why these specific lines of code are important, alternatives, and just want more clarity of why the authors went this direction when setting up this pattern.

Part 1:

```js
static _jQueryInterface(config) {
  return this.each(function () {
    let data = $(this).data(DATA_KEY)

    if (!data) {
      data = new Button(this)
      $(this).data(DATA_KEY, data)
    }

    if (config === 'toggle') {
      data[config]()
    }
  })
}
```

Part 2:

```js
$.fn[NAME]             = Button._jQueryInterface
$.fn[NAME].Constructor = Button
$.fn[NAME].noConflict  = function () {
  $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT
  return Button._jQueryInterface
}
```

Full source:

```js
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.2): button.js
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

const Button = (($) => {


  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Constants
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  const NAME = 'button'
  const VERSION = '4.0.0-alpha.2'
  const DATA_KEY = 'bs.button'
  const EVENT_KEY = `.${DATA_KEY}`
  const DATA_API_KEY = '.data-api'
  const JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME]

  const ClassName = {
    ACTIVE: 'active',
    BUTTON: 'btn',
    FOCUS: 'focus'
  }

  const Selector = {
    DATA_TOGGLE_CARROT: '[data-toggle^="button"]',
    DATA_TOGGLE: '[data-toggle="buttons"]',
    INPUT: 'input',
    ACTIVE: '.active',
    BUTTON: '.btn'
  }

  const Event = {
    CLICK_DATA_API: `click${EVENT_KEY}${DATA_API_KEY}`,
    FOCUS_BLUR_DATA_API: `focus${EVENT_KEY}${DATA_API_KEY} ` + `blur${EVENT_KEY}${DATA_API_KEY}`
  }


  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Class Definition
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  class Button {

    constructor(element) {
      this._element = element
    }


    // getters

    static get VERSION() {
      return VERSION
    }


    // public

    toggle() {
      let triggerChangeEvent = true
      let rootElement = $(this._element).closest(
        Selector.DATA_TOGGLE
      )[0]

      if (rootElement) {
        let input = $(this._element).find(Selector.INPUT)[0]

        if (input) {
          if (input.type === 'radio') {
            if (input.checked &&
              $(this._element).hasClass(ClassName.ACTIVE)) {
              triggerChangeEvent = false

            } else {
              let activeElement = $(rootElement).find(Selector.ACTIVE)[0]

              if (activeElement) {
                $(activeElement).removeClass(ClassName.ACTIVE)
              }
            }
          }

          if (triggerChangeEvent) {
            input.checked = !$(this._element).hasClass(ClassName.ACTIVE)
            $(this._element).trigger('change')
          }
        }
      } else {
        this._element.setAttribute('aria-pressed', !$(this._element).hasClass(ClassName.ACTIVE))
      }

      if (triggerChangeEvent) {
        $(this._element).toggleClass(ClassName.ACTIVE)
      }
    }

    dispose() {
      $.removeData(this._element, DATA_KEY)
      this._element = null
    }


    // static

    static _jQueryInterface(config) {
      return this.each(function() {
        let data = $(this).data(DATA_KEY)

        if (!data) {
          data = new Button(this)
          $(this).data(DATA_KEY, data)
        }

        if (config === 'toggle') {
          data[config]()
        }
      })
    }

  }


  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Data Api implementation
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  $(document)
    .on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE_CARROT, (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()

      let button = event.target

      if (!$(button).hasClass(ClassName.BUTTON)) {
        button = $(button).closest(Selector.BUTTON)
      }

      Button._jQueryInterface.call($(button), 'toggle')
    })
    .on(Event.FOCUS_BLUR_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE_CARROT, (event) => {
      let button = $(event.target).closest(Selector.BUTTON)[0]
      $(button).toggleClass(ClassName.FOCUS, /^focus(in)?$/.test(event.type))
    })


  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * jQuery
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  $.fn[NAME] = Button._jQueryInterface
  $.fn[NAME].Constructor = Button
  $.fn[NAME].noConflict = function() {
    $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT
    return Button._jQueryInterface
  }

  return Button

})(jQuery)

export default Button
```

Thanks so much any input, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Agree. I understand what's going on but it's not clear HOW exactly this code works. Some how they are assigning the DATA_KEY to this component so that they can delegate events related to the specific component with a global event listener on the body. But it is not clear how the assignment works...

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$(document).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_TOGGLE_CARROT, (event) => {
```

equivalates to

```
$(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', (event) => {
```

According to [jQuery's `on` docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) you can namespace event names to avoid removing attached events that are not your own. Thus, a button can have two `on` events, on that's BS4 and one that is your own code for instance.

The [`^` is a selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for "begins with".

The reason this works is because if you want the toggle state on a BS4 button you have to create the button with the data attribute of [`data-toggle='button'`](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#toggle-states)

The [`noConflict`](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/javascript/#no-conflict) works [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/qsecshep/). Basically it allows you to reassign the Bootstrap plugin/modal to a different variable.

```
var f = $.fn.button.noConflict();
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = f;
$('#bt2').click(function() {
  $('#bt1').bootstrapBtn('toggle');
})
```